# Finding marginal PDF fy(y). Can someone check my work?

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus

joint pdf for random variables x,y is:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = c*e^{-x}*e^{-y}\space\space\space 0\leq x \leq 1 \space\space\space y \geq x$$
Find marginal PDF $f_Y(y)$
My attempt:
$$f_Y(y) = c\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x}e^{-y}dx$$
$$f_Y(y) = ce^{-y}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x}dx$$
$$f_Y(y) = ce^{-y}[-e^{-1}+1]$$
$$f_Y(y) = ce^{-y}(1-e^{-1})\space\space\space y\geq x$$
For some reason I don't think this is correct. Can someone check my work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain can be equally represented as 
$$ \{0 \le y \le 1, \ x \le y\} \cup \{y > 1,\ x \le 1 \} $$

You can prove this on your own by graphing the region.

Then we have

$$ \int_0^1\int_x^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \ dy\ dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx\ dy + \int_1^{\infty}\int_0^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx\ dy = 1 $$

We also know that
$$ \int_0^\infty f_Y(y)\ dy = 1 $$

Therefore
$$ f_Y(y) = \left\{ \begin{aligned} \int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx &,\quad 0 \le y \le 1 \\ \int_0^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx &,\quad y > 1 \end{aligned}\right. $$

As you probably realize, the final result should not have any dependence on $x$

Comment: Got it, thanks!
Just a quick question. These two should have the same end value correct?
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{\infty}c*y*e^{-x}*e^{-y}dydx$$
and
$$f_Y(y) = \left\{ \begin{aligned} \int_0^y y*f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx &,\quad 0 \le y \le 1 \\ \int_0^1 y*f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx &,\quad y > 1 \end{aligned}\right.$$
Also, am I understanding the original support area correctly?
https://i.imgur.com/Erbrz7l.png

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Both integral representations should give the expected value of $y$. So $$ \iint yf_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx\ dy = \int y\ f_Y(y)\ dy $$

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition that is it not correct is right; after all, marginal PDF of y should not be depending on x at all.

The main mistake you did was with your integration bounds; for a given y, x does NOT take the values between 0 to 1, but from 0 to <s>y</s> min(y,1). Fixing that, you can carry the algebra forward.

Also, your instructor might expect for you to compute c, which you can by the fact that everything should integrate to 1.

Comment: This is only partially true as $y$ is unbounded, so $x$ goes from $0$ to $y$ if and only if $y \in [0,1]$

Comment: You are absolutely correct